# Android getInputStream fails (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)

Tags: android, http, https

Symptoms:

Unable to complete `getInputStream`. It fails with code (`HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238`)

Original error log:

> 05-25 17:57:06.473 2675-2722/com.manantial.raul.photogallery E/TAG: FlickrFetchr Failed to fetch items
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getRecent&api_key=6f722a706254ed716d5abb9fb1f012c7&extras=url_s
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
>           at com.manantial.raul.photogallery.FlickrFetchr.getUrlBytes(FlickrFetchr.java:37)
>           at com.manantial.raul.photogallery.FlickrFetchr.getUrl(FlickrFetchr.java:69)
>           at com.manantial.raul.photogallery.FlickrFetchr.fetchItems(FlickrFetchr.java:79)
>           at com.manantial.raul.photogallery.PhotoGalleryFragment$FetchItemsTask.doInBackground(PhotoGalleryFragment.java:45)
>           at com.manantial.raul.photogallery.PhotoGalleryFragment$FetchItemsTask.doInBackground(PhotoGalleryFragment.java:36)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

---

`HttpURLConnection getResponseCode` = 403 / HTPP_FORBIDDEN

---

When using the same URL via web browser, there is no error and `getResponseCode` is OK / 200.

Facts:

Code used:

```
try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream(); // fails, while HttpURLConnection = HTTP_FORBIDDEN 403


        if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {  // connection resp code 403 FORBIDDEN
            return null;
        }


        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        out.close();
        String temp = out.toByteArray().toString();
        Log.i("TAG", TAG + "out.toByteArray is the data response: " + temp);
        return out.toByteArray();


    } finally {
        Log.i("TAG", TAG + " connection response code: " + connection.getResponseCode());
        connection.disconnect();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The URL used in the code was:

http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getRecent&api_key=6f722a706254ed716d5abb9fb1f012c7&extras=url_s

That was converted to https, when using it via browser, but not when using it via my test Android App. The solution was simply adjusting the URL to https in the code:

https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getRecent&api_key=6f722a706254ed716d5abb9fb1f012c7&extras=url_s